# PowerShell : how do you run a folder size summation?

Tags: powershell

My objective is to write a copy script which moves files from one directory, "d:\aa1", to "d:\aa2" up to a specified size of another directory, "d:\bbb". In other words... I'd like it to copy all files from "d:\aa1" to "d:\aa2" until the size of "d:\aa1" is the same size or less than "d:\bbb".

So far I have

```
$lmt = get-childitem d:\bbb  | measure-object -property length -sum 
do { get-childitem -path d:\aa1 | move-item -destination "d:\aa2" } while {measure-object {$_.sum -lt $lmt}
```

But the syntax doesn't seem to be working. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-ChildItem -path d:\aa1 `
| % {if (((Get-ChildItem d:\aa2 `
| Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum + $_.Length) `
-lt (Get-ChildItem d:\bbb | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum) `
{Move-Item $_.FullName d:\aa2}}
```

Comment: Better than mine since it checks the total before the copy.

Comment: I think you are missing an _ in $.length. I think it should be $_.Length.

Comment: It is $_.Length in Edit textbox, so I had to change to code format.

Comment: Can you split up the lines after each pipe symbol, it will make your code easier to read. Not a big deal

Comment: I'm getting an error saying Measure-object : property "length" cannot be found in any objects input

Comment: Somewhere you need | Where-Object ($_.Attributes -match "Directory")

Comment: You also need to specify -recurse with Get-ChildItem if you want the sum to include files in subdirectories, and -force if there are hidden files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a property or method for the sum of a directory.You can add options to 'ls' as needed for the script below:

```
rv total;
foreach ($i in ((ls -Force) | Select Length)) {[int64]$total+=$i[0].Length};
$total /1GB;
```